# Matching values from different columns, GOOGLE SHEETS

Tags: google-sheets

Google sheets,

I have columns a with 5000 rows and column b with 3000 rows.

How to check if value from A1,A2,A3 ETC is in B1:B3000 so I would see 5000 rows in column C with either True or False?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this formula work as you want if pasted into cell C2:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,IF(COUNTIF(B2:B,A2:A)=0,"False","True")))`